# Post URL with PHP script

Tags: php, url, post, send

I have a little issue. I generate an URL with my PHP script like this :

```
http://emoncms.org/input/post.json?json={CONSO:1.5828060}&apikey=MyApiKey
```

I use the code below to send the URL to the Internet, but it doesn't work:

```
$client = new Client('http://emoncms.org'); 
$query ='/input/post.json'; 
$query .= '?json={CONSO:' . $CONSO . '}' . '&apikey=MyApiKey';

$request = $client->post($query); 
$response = $request->send();
```

However, when I put the URL in my browser, it works ! But not with my PHP script... :(

Can you help me please ?

Comment: Use the `{}` code markup tool for code, not the quotation tool.

Comment: it seems the php script handles `$_GET` and not `$_POST`

Comment: you don't need to quote `MyApiKey`

Comment: You've got a syntax error above anyways. `'&apikey='MyApiKey'` is invalid PHP - unbalanced `'`-quotes.

Comment: You should use `urlencode()` to encode the characters in the `json` parameter. And it doesn't look like valid JSON, there are no quotes around the `CONSO` property name.

Comment: Use `json_encode()` to create valid JSON.

Comment: Yes, error with copy/paste...

Comment: Like this ? $query .= '?json={CONSO:' . json_encode($CONSO) . '&apikey=MyApiKey';

Comment: No, like `'?json=' . urlencode(json_encode(array('CONSO'=>$CONSO))) . '&apikey=MyApiKey'`

Answer (score 0):

Please do as follows.

```
$client = new Client('http://emoncms.org'); 
$query ='/input/post.json'; 
$MyApiKey = "yourapikey";
$query .= '?json={CONSO:' . $CONSO . '}' . '&apikey='.$MyApiKey;

$request = $client->post($query); 
$response = $request->send();
```

Comment: please include ur apikey in $MyApiKey variable and assign $conso variable to 1.5828060

Comment: Yes I do, the solution is with json_encode()  :)
Thanks for your help ;)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using cURL to post data to a url from PHP. You can do it your way, I just prefer cURL myself.

I have built several APIs using this method:

```
    $ch = curl_init('http://emoncms.org/input/post.json');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

You assign `$post` whatever data you want to post. It accepts an array so instead of doing

```
$query ='/input/post.json'; 
$query .= '?json={CONSO:' . $CONSO . '}' . '&apikey='MyApiKey';
```

You can instead do:

```
$post = array(
    'json'   => "{CONSO:$CONSO}",
    'apikey' => 'api_key_goes_here
);
```

`$result` will be the response from the server. If it is a json response you can simply do `$result = json_decode($result, true);`

If the server needs a query instead of post data, I would change the cURL request to send a query instead of posting. The server may allow either one, but I would just check to make sure.

Also: If you are sending json, why dont you use `json_encode($data);`? I find it a lot better then writing custom json yourself. But it's up to you.